# Cast DataTable to XSD

Tags: c#

Hi I have a date represented by an xsd file, I have to cast from a datatable obtained from a rest call to DataStampaRisorse (xsd) how can I do to perform the cast?

```
 DataStampaRisorse d = new DataStampaRisorse();
 string json = "{\"IdUtenteSelect\":\"" + IdUtenteSelect + "\"," + "\"StartDate\":\"" + StartDate + "\"," + "\"EndData\":\"" + EndData + "\"," + "\"StampaTutteLeRisorse\":\"" + StampaTutteLeRisorse + "\"}";   
 string value = Json.GetString("/RisorseUmane/CaricaRisorseCantiere", json);
 DataTable dt = Json.ConvertJSONtoDataTable(value);
```

Comment: You're saying [XSD](https://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/XSD-XML-Schema-Definition) but the code is JSON. That a service would return XSD also seems unlikely - is it really XML? Or maybe it actually is JSON? From your current description and code it's simple not possible to know for us.

Comment: `XSD` is an XML schema document. You don't *cast* a DataTable to a schema. In any case, assuming the posted code has nothing to do with the question, you can use [DataTable.WriteXmlSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexmlschema?view=netframework-4.8) to generate an XML Schema and write it out as an XSD. DataTables and XML types in .NET were designed to make XML processing as easy as handling tables in a Dataset